# how to using an array from user inputs in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to write a program that will prompt the user for the    number  of  students    in  their   class   and how  many   quizzes each    student took.       After   getting this    information the user    will    be  asked   to  provide the student’s   name    and their   grade   on  each    of  the quizzes.        This    will    continue    until   all students    and their   quiz    grades  have    been    entered.        The program will    then    output  a   table   showing the student’s   name    and their   average from
all entered quiz    grades.

This is not right but it is what I have so far...

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    int students;
    int quizzes;
    int averageArray;
    int studentsArray;
    cout << "Please enter the number of students : " << endl;
    cin >> students;
    cout << "Please enter the number of quizzes : " << endl;
    cin >> quizzes;
    averageArray = new int [quizzes];
    studentsArray = new int [students];
    for (int i = 0; i <= students; i++)
        cout << "Enter the student's name: ";
    cin >> studentsArray[i];
    for (int j = 0; j <= quizzes; j++)
        cout << "Enter quiz score: ";
    cin >> averageArray[j];
}
```

Comment: Search StackOverflow (or the internet) for "c++ students quiz" for examples of your homework assignment.

Comment: You need to use `{` and `}` after the `for` statement, always.  Make it a habit and mistakes like yours will be reduced.

Comment: Also, use `std::vector` and more issues will disappear.

Comment: I don't see any meaningful questions here.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a definite answer, but your code needs to be rewritten, and I can't be asked at the moment, so here's some hints:

-Use a map of a string and a multiset of doubles to hold each student's score

-Read each student one at a time, keeping their names in a string and using the subscript operator to push back into the multiset the score.

-If it's easier on you, you can use a vector instead of a multiset

-Use 2 for loops and have the stopping point for each be the 2 integers you read into at the start

-At the end, loop through each element in the map and calculate the average score (then and there) using a double to store it one at a time.